# Звук в pyttsx3 ужасный как исправить?

Tags: python, linux, pyttsx3

У `pyttsx3` ужасный звук и на русском и на английском. На русском вообще ничего не понятно. Я испоьзую ОС Linux на основе  Debian. Такая проблема есть в `espeak`. Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Espeak не имеет записанных сэмплов голоса. Звуки воспроизводятся по частотной модели и нет возможности заменить их и както поправить.

Для Виндовс и Мак pyttsx3 использует системные голоса. В случае Линуксов я бы посоветовал заменить синтезатор голоса на облачный.

Comment: Но облачные синтезаторы работают очень медленно. Зависит ли это от скорость сети? И можно ли как то ускорить?

Comment: Разбивай текст на предложения и фразы. Короткие обрабатываются быстрее.